# Spring cloud Kafka multiple Brokers with SSL

Tags: spring-boot, spring-kafka, spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka

In my project i need to connect to two different Kafka brokers via SSL

My application.yml looks somewhat like this:

```
spring:
  cloud:
    stream:
      binders:
        kafka-1:
          type: kafka
          environment:
            spring:
              cloud:
                stream:
                  kafka:
                    binder:
                      brokers: *url-1*
        kafka-2:
          type: kafka
          environment:
            spring:
              cloud:
                stream:
                  kafka:
                    binder:
                      brokers: *url-2*
```

It works if there in no need in authorization on kafka server.

But the thing is - I need to use different SSL settings for both of them!

The only property where i found possibility to use different ssl settings is:

```
spring:
  kafka:
    producer:
      ssl:
        trust-store-location: ...
        ...
    consumer:
      ssl:
        trust-store-location: ...
        ...
```

but it doesn't work for my case and doesn't make any sence either

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put those under each `environment` node in the YAML.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Gary Russell i ended with working properties like this:

```
spring:
  cloud:
    stream:
      binders:
        kafka-1:
          type: kafka
          environment:
            spring:
              kafka:
                ssl:
                  protocol: SSL
                  key-store-location:...
                  key-password:...
                  trust-store-location:...
                  trust-store-password:...
              cloud:
                stream:
                  kafka:
                    binder:
                      confuguration:
                        security.protocol: SSL
                        ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm: ''
                      brokers: *url-1*
        kafka-2:
          type: kafka
          environment:
            spring:
              cloud:
                stream:
                  kafka:
                    binder:
                      brokers: *url-2*
```